# Does Ruby Enterprise use Green threads?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I was wondering this and couldn't find anything except [this](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/documentation.html#_overview_of_ruby_enterprise_edition_ree)

"Thread scheduler bug fixes and performance improvements. Threading on Ruby Enterprise Edition can be more than 10 times faster than official Ruby 1.8"

Comment: I wish information came with a "use by" date!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

REE is derived from MRI 1.8.7. As such, it only used green threads. REE changes some parts of 1.8.7 (esp. in the areas memory management and garbage collection). But it still widely follows the design of the upstream MRI (the original Matz's Ruby Interpreter)

While YARV (1.9) switched to OS native threads, they still have a global interpreter lock making sure that only exactly one of these threads runs at a time.

There are a couple of Ruby implementations with OS native threads and without a GIL. The most prominent are JRuby (based on the JVM) and Rubinius (with its own VM). These implementations offer "real" concurrent threads.

Comment: +1 though I wanted to point out that the GIL is not always in effect when using Ruby threads. Therefore it often *does* make sense to use threads, even if it would be counter-intuitive with a concept such as the GIL.

Comment: Well, with a GIL, you can still model "concurrent" sequences. So while each instruction is only executed one after another, the code flows (or sequences) are concurrent. This allows things like EventMachine to be very efficient even on GILed implementations.

Answer (score 5):

Besides JRuby and Rubinius, who have got rid of an interpreter lock entirely, the state of affairs in CRuby/MRI has also made some progress with regard to concurrency.

One notable feature is that with the [Bitmap Marking GC](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/41916) by Narihiro Nakamura, as of Ruby 2.0, another advantage of REE over CRuby will be gone: REE has a copy on write-friendly GC algorithm which made it attractive for achieving concurrency through processes (forking) rather than through threading. The new Bitmap Marking GC will have the [same advantage](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/3/23/why-you-should-be-excited-about-garbage-collection-in-ruby-2-0) of saving unnecessary copying of memory around when forking a new process.

The GIL (or GVL as it is officially called) is also not quite as bad as it sounds at first. For example, Ruby releases the interpreter lock [when doing IO](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/02/06/the-ruby-global-interpreter-lock/). Another feature that we see much more often lately is that C extension developers have the ability to manually release the lock by calling `rb_thread_blocking_region`, which will execute a C-level function with the GIL released. This can have huge effects if some operation in C is to be performed where we can rest assured that it will have no side effects. A nice example is [RSA key generation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/openssl/ossl_pkey_rsa.c#L136) - this runs completely in C with memory allocated by OpenSSL, so we can run it safely with the GIL released.

Fibers introduced in 1.9 or recent projects like [Celluloid](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid) also cast a much more friendly light on the state of Ruby concurrency today as when compared to a few years ago.

Last not least, Koichi Sasada, the author of CRuby's VM, is actively working on the MVM technology, which will allow to run multiple VMs in a single Ruby process, and therefore achieving concurrency in yet another way.

Taking all the other performance improvements into account, there are less and less arguments for using REE, it's safe to switch to 1.9.3 or 2.0.0 once it's out, especially since the 1.8 series will no longer be actively developed and many popular projects have announced to quit their support for 1.8 sometime soon.

Edit:

As Holger pointed out, REE has also been [EOLed](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/02/21/ruby-enterprise-edition-1-8-7-2012-02-released-end-of-life-imminent/), and there will be no port to 1.9 or further. So it's not only safe to switch, but also the right thing to do :)

Comment: +1. It could be added that [REE is officially EOLed](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/02/21/ruby-enterprise-edition-1-8-7-2012-02-released-end-of-life-imminent/) and will not be ported to the 1.9 series.

Comment: @HolgerJust Yes, good point. Not only safe to switch, but actually the right thing to do :) I'll add your remark.

Comment: Great info, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @echristopherson: You're right. And Holger did a great job at that. My answer was more a reply to "REE is ten times faster than Ruby 1.8", wanted to point out that this is no longer true for current versions.